# TensorRT 5.1 has no attribute create_inference_graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorrt

I want to optimize my neural network (Resnet101 from Google) for inference with TensorRT (ver. 5.1). I've been looking for blogs and tutorials how to do it and found some stuff like [here](https://medium.com/tensorflow/speed-up-tensorflow-inference-on-gpus-with-tensorrt-13b49f3db3fa) and a few other. All of them have one common thing:

```
trt_graph = trt.create_inference_graph(
                getNetwork(network_file_name), 
                outputs,
                max_batch_size=batch_size,
                max_workspace_size_bytes=workspace_size, 
                precision_mode=”INT8")
```

But the problem is that my version of TensorRT does not have such function. I get an output as below.

```
Python 3.6.6 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)
>>> import tensorrt as trt
>>> trt.__version__
5.1.2.2
>>> trt.create_inference_graph()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'tensorrt' has no attribute 'create_inference_graph'
```

Does anyone know if that function was replaced with other in version 5.1 of TensorRT? How to run it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Uziel suggested Tensorrt should be used with:

`import tensorflow.contrib.tensorrt as trt`

Unfortunately in my case that import caused a following error:

`tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: libnvinfer.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

There was a problem with my installation of TensorRT. After reinstalling everything it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Some installations of tensorflow already have tensorrt by default. Try with;

`import tensorflow.contrib.tensorrt as trt`

Answer (score 1):

This is also another location from where you can import tensorrt

```
from tensorflow.python.compiler.tensorrt import trt_convert as trt
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me when using TF1.5 with TRT5.0 on Python3